# How can i insert multiple record into a table at runtime PL SQL on (apex.oracle.com)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, bulkinsert

I want to insert new records into the table at runtime. and I'm using **apex.oracle.com** platform.

I have created the following table:-

`CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(ID VARCHAR2(10),NAME VARCHAR2(50),COURSE VARCHAR2(10),MOBILE NUMBER(10),EMAIL VARCHAR2(50));`

And create this procedure to insert record into the table:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "INSERTRECORD" (ID IN VARCHAR2,NAME IN VARCHAR2,COURSE IN VARCHAR2,MOBILE IN NUMBER,EMAIL IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES(ID,NAME,COURSE,MOBILE,EMAIL);
END;
```

```
DECLARE
RECORD_SIZE NUMBER := 2;
ID VARCHAR2(10);
NAME VARCHAR2(50);
COURSE VARCHAR2(10);
MOBILE NUMBER(10);
EMAIL VARCHAR2(50);
I NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR I IN 1..RECORD_SIZE LOOP
ID:=:ID;
NAME:=:NAME;
COURSE:=:COURSE;
MOBILE:=:MOBILE;
EMAIL:=:EMAIL;
INSERTRECORD(ID,NAME,COURSE,MOBILE,EMAIL);
END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm not able to insert record at runtime given by the user....I am getting this error.
Can someone fix this ? Or can help me out in inserting records into table at runtime.

**Error:-**

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "WKSP_CUPLSQL.INSERTRECORD", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 16
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


2. RECORD_SIZE NUMBER := 2;
3. ID VARCHAR2(10);
4. NAME VARCHAR2(50);
5. COURSE VARCHAR2(10);
6. MOBILE NUMBER(10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/SQL is not an interactive language. It is SQL*Plus that is prompting you for a value and it needs to get all the substitution values it needs before it can send the PL/SQL block to the database to be executed. There is no way for PL/SQL to prompt the user for input so there is no way to prompt for input in a PL/SQL loop.

If you are trying to get a user to enter a number of values where the number of values they need to enter is not known at compile time, you would generally be better served writing a small application (a shell script, a Perl script, a tiny C application, etc.) in a language that supports user interaction and giving that to the users. Let the application get the user input and then pass that to the PL/SQL process.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure why you need a procedure. In Oracle, to insert multiple rows into table t with columns col1, col2 and col3 you can use the following syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val1_1', 'val1_2', 'val1_3')
   INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val2_1', 'val2_2', 'val2_3')
   INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val3_1', 'val3_2', 'val3_3')
   .
   .
   .
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

Or

INSERT  INTO t (col1, col2, col3) 
   SELECT 'val1_1', 'val1_2', 'val1_3' from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'val1_4', 'val1_5', 'val1_6'
FROM DUAL
```

The thing to remember here is to use the from dual statement.

Comment: Suppose I want to insert 10 new records and want to take input from user. In my case, ID,NAME,COURSE,MOBILE,EMAIL. Every time I want, user must give input and that record should be inserted into table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me.

```
DECLARE
    record_count NUMBER := 10;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..record_count
    LOOP
        insertrecord (:id, :student_name, :course, :mobile, :email);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

NAME is an Oracle keyword, so it's not a good column or variable name. I changed it to student_name.

Comment: FOR i IN 1..record_count
creates a NUMBER variable called i. You don't need to explicitly declare it. If you do declare a variable called i, it will be separate from the i used inside the loop. For example, try running this anonymous block:

DECLARE
 i NUMBER := 10;
BEGIN
 dbms_output.put_line (i || ' = i before loop');

 FOR i IN 1 .. 3
 LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line (i || ' = i inside loop');
 END LOOP;
 
 dbms_output.put_line (i || ' = i after loop');
END;
/
Look at the output:

10 = i before loop
1 = i inside loop
2 = i inside loop
3 = i inside loop
10 = i after loop

Comment: Thanks Dear :) It also worked for me and I also got the point of explicitly declaring i variable. Thanks for your help. But The above code is also inserting the user inputted data  RECORD_COUNT times.  Suppose  id = '21mba1010', student_name = 'Akhand' , course = 'mba', mobile = xxxxxxxxxx, email = 'abc@gmail.com' . This one record is being inserted into the table RECORD_COUNT times. What i want is it must ask me to insert data every time.... Is it possible ????